# Removing files using update installer MSP

Tags: windows-installer, installation, orca

I am in the process of attepting to build an Microsoft installer update (MSP) where I would like to have the update installer remove files from the original installation.

I have succceessfully created a new msi, which when viewed in Orca.exe, I can see the RemoveFile table has the correct entry included, but after generating the *.msp file and executing, the files requested for removal still remain...

If anyone can help, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The MSI Component rules inhibit you from deleting Components during a Minor Upgrade or Small Update. However Phil Wilson's answer to [this question here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d5c750f7-2e82-4ea7-a2a8-96f41d97e374/removing-files-during-minor-upgrades) provides a novel solution to that: Add decimal 64 to the to-be-deleted files' Component's "Attributes" entry in the Component table. The flag he references, msidbComponentAttributesTransitive, is documented in the Component table documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368007.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

File removals are associated with a component install or uninstall. So if your associated component is not being installed by the patch, the removal is not performed.

An easier approach is to use a custom action:

- write a [custom action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368066%28VS.85%29.aspx) which removes your file
- add it in your new MSI
- set this condition for it:

  PATCH